# Why is a Lorentz transformation of a Lorentz transformation also a Lorentz transformation?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, group-theory

Why is a Lorentz transformation of a Lorentz transformation ($x''$,$y''$,$z''$,$t''$) also a Lorentz transformation?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 3):

*I'll assume that the motion is in the only x-direction.*

You can define the Lorentz transformation as 
$$P^{\overline{\alpha}} = \Lambda^{\overline{\alpha}}_\beta~P^{\beta}~~(1)$$

where $P^{\overline{\alpha}} =(P^{\overline{0}}P^{\overline{1}},P^{\overline{2}},P^{\overline{3}})$(represents the coordinate of an event measured by $O'$, which moves with a velocity $v_1$ with respect to an observer $O$) and $P^{\beta} = (P^0, P^1, P^2, P^3)$ (represents the coordinate of an event measured by $O$).

$$\Lambda^{\overline{\alpha}}_\beta = \begin{pmatrix}
\gamma_1 & -v_1\gamma_1 & 0 & 0 \\
-v_1\gamma_1 & \gamma_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Let us write a Lorentz transformation between $O''$ and $O'$.

$$P^{\overline{\overline{\nu}}} = \Lambda^{\overline{\overline{\nu}}}_{\overline{\alpha}}~ P^{\overline{\alpha}}~~(2)$$

Here $P^{\overline{\overline{\nu}}}$ represents the coordinate of an event measured by $O''$, which moves with a velocity $+v_2$ to an observer $O'$.

In this case

$$\Lambda^{\overline{\overline{\nu}}}_{\overline{\alpha}}  = \begin{pmatrix}
\gamma_2 & -v_2\gamma_2 & 0 & 0 \\
-v_2\gamma_2 & \gamma_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

We can combine Eqn $(1)$ and $(2)$ to write

$$P^{\overline{\overline{\nu}}} = \Lambda^{\overline{\overline{\nu}}}_{\overline{\alpha}} ~\Lambda^{\overline{\alpha}}_\beta~P^{\beta}$$

Where $$\Lambda^{\overline{\overline{\nu}}}_{\overline{\alpha}} ~\Lambda^{\overline{\alpha}}_\beta =\Lambda^{\overline{\overline{\nu}}}_\beta =\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma_2 & -v_2\gamma_2 & 0 & 0 \\
-v_2\gamma_2 & \gamma_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma_1 & -v_1\gamma_1 & 0 & 0 \\
-v_1\gamma_1 & \gamma_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
As you can see $\Lambda^{\overline{\overline{\nu}}}_\beta$ is also a Lorentz transformation matrix, which is the multiplication of the two transformation matrices.

Thus we can write

$$P^{\overline{\overline{\nu}}} = \Lambda^{\overline{\overline{\nu}}}_\beta P^{\beta}$$

In principle, you can extend this transformation for any observer which is an inertial reference frame.

Comment: I'd suggest that mixing capital $A$ and capital $\Lambda$ creates some potential for confusion in reading this.

Comment: @StephenG Noted

Comment: Why did you choose to consider only two-dimensional Lorentz transformations, instead of the full set of four-dimensional Lorentz transformations? Can you guarantee that your finding will be the same in the four-dimensional case?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye I think it should...

Comment: It probably does, but here you are just showing it for the two-dimensional case, not for the general case.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye. I just did it for simplicity...You can improve it if you wish

Comment: In particular, a two-dimensional Lorentz transform involving time and one spatial dimension is a kind of Lorentz boost, which is a subset of the Lorentz transforms.

Comment: I understand you did it for simplicity, and that’s okay. I’m just saying that it sounds like you’re framing it as if you had made the proof for the general case, which you have not.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye you are indeed right

Answer (score 2):

You're asking the wrong question. You don't apply a Lorentz transformation (LT) to a transformation, you apply a Lorentz transformation to an inertial reference frame (1) to get a description of an event (or events) in another inertial reference frame (2). That LT will preserve the space-time quantity $$c^2t_1^2-r_1^2 = c^2t_2^2-r_2^2.$$

If that is true (and it is) it doesn't matter what the initial frame is. You can always apply LT to get a different frame that preserves. Each LT will "boost" a frame (non-linearly related to $\beta$ -- $\beta=\tanh s$). And the application of an LT twice or thrice or more always produces the equivalent of a single LT with a matching boost sum.

**Edit Addition:** 
If the relative velocity between two frames is $\beta c$, then we can represent \begin{align}
\gamma &= \cosh s \newline
\gamma\beta &= \sinh s \end{align}
where $s$ is called the boost of the LT.

It can be shown (a good exercise for those in COVID-19 isolation) that $$LT(s_1)LT(s_2) = LT(s_1+s_2).$$

Comment: Just some semantics. In any frame, the LT to $O''$ is a frame dependent thing (like four momentum), so the LT from $O'\rightarrow O''$ is a transformation of the LT from $O\rightarrow O''$ derived by applying the LT from $O\rightarrow O'$.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Landau&Livshitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#Landau_&_Lifshitz_solution) Lorentz transformation is a (hyperbolic) rotation in time-space. Rotation after a rotation is also a rotation.

Comment: Downvoted because Lorentz transformations are not rotations. Adding "in time-space" does not make them rotations.

Comment: @GiorgioComitini I modified my answer, since treating Lorentz transformations as rotations is not my idea.

Comment: The old physicists thought of the boost elements of LTs as space-time rotations by imaginary angles.  Equivalently, the boosts are space-time strains by real angles.  You will notice the similarity of the space-space strain parallelpipeding  done to a cube of material by engineers and the space-time strain parallelpipeding done to the space-time axes by a physicist.  An engineer's strain in the xy plane leaves $x^2-y^2$ invariant just like a physicist's boost leaves $t^2-x^2$ invariant.  Rotations and strains makeup the transformations of the group $GL(4,R)$.

Answer (score 1):

All the Lorentz transformations of Minkowski spacetime form a group -- [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group). By closure law, LT followed by LT is just another LT.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it doesn't answer the question, merely restate it. The fact that it is a group requires closure being independently checked which is what OP is asking for.

Comment: It depends on the premise of the question: if it is about the group theory, then the closure must be proved. If it is about the relativity, then the closure is implied, since relativity is a consequence of the Lorentz symmetry and not the other way around.

Comment: @jacob1729: The op's question "why" includes proving LT*LT=LT, but it would be a disservice to not include in "why" the physical reason this property is important. The physical  acts of rotating and boosting that we do with our fingers to an object in the real world obey the axioms of being a continuous group.  The product of 2 elements is in the group, for every element there is an inverse element, there is a identity (ie: do nothing), and the transformations are done by continuous parameters. Miraculously, there is a mathematical group $O(3,1)$ which copies these physical actions.

Comment: @jacob1729: I'm upgrading  the answer because of my innate skill at reading OP's mind - it does answer the question

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you want a mathematical proof. You can see in Reign's answer a particular case, but here I will post a more general one.

As you may know, a Lorentz transformation can be written as a 4-dimensional matrix, $\Lambda$, so that $x' = \Lambda x$. This matrix must fulfill this relation,

\begin{equation}
\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda = \eta
\end{equation}

where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric.

If you consider a Lorentz transformation you are thinking of $x' = \Lambda_1 x$. A Lorentz transformation of a Lorentz transformation is then $x'' = \Lambda_2 x' = \Lambda_2 \Lambda_1 x$. Now, you have a transformation matrix $\Lambda = \Lambda_2 \Lambda_1$ and you would like to know whether this new matrix $\Lambda$ is a Lorentz transformation or not. To do this, take the previous equation and do some calculations:

\begin{equation}
\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda = (\Lambda_2 \Lambda_1)^T \eta (\Lambda_2 \Lambda_1) = (\Lambda_1)^T (\Lambda_2)^T \eta \Lambda_2 \Lambda_1
\end{equation}

Now, you can use that $(\Lambda_2)^T \eta \Lambda_2 = \eta$ because $\Lambda_2$ is a Lorentz transformation, so that you get

\begin{equation}
\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda = (\Lambda_1)^T \eta \Lambda_1
\end{equation}

For the same reason you can use that $(\Lambda_1)^T \eta \Lambda_1 = \eta$.

Finally you get 
\begin{equation}
\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda = \eta
\end{equation}
where $\Lambda = \Lambda_2 \Lambda_1$. This proofs that a Lorentz transformation of a Lorentz transformation is a Lorentz transformation.